# View Controller disappearing after Segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a customer tab controller that has a custom icon that when a user clicks a popup menu comes up with 3 choices. When I click the first option it should take me to a new view controller, however when I click it the view controller only appears for a second before disappearing again. I'm not sure why but here is my code for the customer tab bar:

```swift
import UIKit
import PopMenu

class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if viewController.title == "for custom action" {
            let manager = PopMenuManager.default

            let action1 = PopMenuDefaultAction(title: "Scan Barcode", didSelect: { action in

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showScanBarcode", sender: nil)
                print("\(String(describing: action.title)) is tapped")
            })

            let action2 = PopMenuDefaultAction(title: "Action 2", didSelect: { action in

                print("\(String(describing: action.title)) is tapped")
            })

            let action3 = PopMenuDefaultAction(title: "Action 3", image: UIImage(named: "wine"), didSelect: { action in
                print("\(String(describing: action.title)) is tapped")
            })

            manager.addAction(action1)
            manager.addAction(action2)
            manager.addAction(action3)

            manager.present()


            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {

            let controller = segue.destination as! myViewController

            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true

        }
    }

}
```

Here is an image showing the flow. User clicks the camera button, then a popup menu appears and when the user clicks on an option I want to take them to a new view controller (not connected to tab bar controller). I setup the first link to go to a new view controller, and it shows for a few seconds then disappears.

[image]

Comment: What kind of segue does `showScanBarcode` do (push, pop, present)? Add more code details such as storyboard and  `showScanBarcode`s viewcontroller class

Comment: It is a push segue, created in IB with identifier showScanBarcode ... the scowScanBarcode class is just empty for now it is just a template

Comment: Is TabBarController embedded in a `UINavigationController` for the push segue to work?   " view controller only appears for a second before disappearing again" please expound on this

Comment: I added more info in the description, the TabBarController is NOT embedded in a navigation controller, however some screens within the TBC are embedded. When they click the middle icon a custom popup appears that I want the user to click one of the options and be led to a separate view controller not associated with the tab bar controller, if that makes sense

Comment: If that's the case, then shouldn't the segue be inside a specific viewController of TBC?

Comment: So there is no underlying viewController for that tab bar iconic the TBC, it just shows the custom popup menu and from there I want to handle the segue

Comment: I don't think this will solve the issue, but could you please add `super.viewDidLoad()` as a first line of `func viewDidLoad()` implementation in your code? Regularly such methods overrides as `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear,` etc. should call parent methods, otherwise, it can introduce really unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @user2647092 I think you need to update (segue.identifier == "mySegue") to (segue.identifier == "showScanBarcode")

Comment: `manager.present()` is this a UIView or are you presenting another `UIViewController`?

Comment: Does this PopMenuDefaultAction is an UIViewController or just an UIView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a problem with PopMenue.

PopMenuManager is displaying a UIViewController on the topmost view controller and calls dismiss() after a selection. Dismiss goes recursive through all controller. By the time he does that, is your new view controller the topmost and receives the dismiss. 
It might help to do the segue in a separate thread. (Along with a short delay for testing maybe)

```
    let action1 = PopMenuDefaultAction(title: "Scan Barcode", didSelect: { action in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showScanBarcode", sender: nil)
        }
        print("\(String(describing: action.title)) is tapped")
    })
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using different identifier for segue method,

`performSegue(withIdentifier: "showScanBarcode", sender: nil)`

AND

`prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`.

So, please use same identifier.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're storing `action1` in `manager` and that is local to this function.  So, after the function finishes execution then `manager`, and its contents, go out of scope and get garbage collected.

To work around this, declare `manager` as an instance variable in the class (outside of the function).  For example:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
   let manager = PopMenuManager.default
   ...
   func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
      ...
      manager.addAction(action1)
   }

}
```